# Plot density of a distribution

Tags: r, function

Is it possible to plot in R the density function of a distribution?
For example suppose that I want to plot the density function of a Normal(0,5) or a Gamma(5,5).

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/probability.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f <- function(x) dnorm(x,0,5)
g <- function(x) dgamma(x,5,5)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))   # set up gaphics window for 2 plots
plot(f,xlim=c(-15,15),main="N(0,5)")
plot(g,xlim=c(0,3),main="Gamma(5,5)")
```

[image]

In R the distribution functions follow a pattern. For instance, for the normal distribution, the PDF is `dnorm(...)`, the CDF is `pnorm(...)`, the inverse CDF (quantile function) is `qnorm(...)`, and the random number generator is `rnorm(...)`.

One thing to watch out for is that R's convention for the arguments does not necessarily match what you find, for instance, on Wikipedia. For instance the arguments to `dgamma(...)` are `x`, `shape`, and `rate`, not `x`, `k`, and `theta`.